# How do I allocate a function call to a variable, and how do i count elements in this function

Tags: function, maple

I am new here, and 'only' a mathematician, so please accept these two very simple questions, that keeps troubling me.

In Maple, the function PrintVar(3) returns 3, now I would like to set B=3 in order to use B later. Only, I cannot do this (see picture).
Then, when I want to count the elements in the functioncall above, ie. I would like to do nops(B), but because of my problem above, I try to do nops(PrintVar(3)), but I am not allowed to do this either (maybe since it is not indexable?).

Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Sincerely Tomas Medici

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that PrintVar() returns NULL because print() returns NULL (it displays its arguments but doesn't return them). You can see this is the case in the output line "C := "

If you want PrintVar to pass through its output so that it is available for assignment, you should write:

```
PrintVar := proc(e1)
    print(e1);
    return e1;
end proc;
```

Comment: You should not write the `print(e1)` line. The printing is handled by the choice of a semi-colon `;` or colon `:` when calling the procedure. That is, without the `print` line, `C := PrintVar(3);` assigns 3 to `C` *and* prints the output, while `C := PrintVar(3):` assigns 3 to `C` silently.

Comment: @Therkel that's true for top level scripting but if PrintVar is called inside another function you will not see it's output. The call to print() allows you to display output no matter how deep the function call is.